# Simplification of $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{n-1}x \sin x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't see how they derived this step, could someone please explain?

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{n-1}x \sin x dx = sin^{n-1}x (-\cos x ) |_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (n-1) \sin^{n-2} x \cos x (- \cos x) dx$$

Comment: Integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $u=\sin^{n-1}(x)$ and $v'=\sin(x)$
then

$u'=(n-1)\sin^{n-2}(x)(\cos(x))$,

$v=-\cos(x)$
and

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}uv'=[uv]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}u'v$$

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from partial integration.

If you choose $f(x) = \sin^{n-1}(x)$ and $g'(x) = \sin(x)$, then you have $g(x) = -\cos(x)$ and $f'(x) = (n - 1) \sin^{n - 2}(x) \cos(x)$.